# replace a key with array in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

Sample json file `payload.json.tpl`:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "x": {
    "y": "${array}"
  }
}
```

I have an array in bash

```
array=("one" "two" "three")
```

How can I run the jq command to replace the key `.x.y` to `["one", "two", "three"]`

So the final json will be:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "x": {
    "y": ["one", "two", "three"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$ARGS.positional` (requires jq 1.6)

```
$ array=("one" "two" "three")
$ jq '.x.y = $ARGS.positional' payload.json.tpl --args "${array[@]}"
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "x": {
    "y": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this, works with jq < 1.6 too:

```
< payload.json.tpl jq --arg a "${array[*]}" '.x.y=($a|split(" "))'
```

Note the use of `${array[*]}` instead of `${array[@]}`. When using `*`, the elements of `${array}` will be passed as a single string instead of multiple strings.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

Comment: It has to be noted that this won't work for arrays whose elements themselves contain spaces, which is the primary reason to use a shell array over a space-separated string in the first place. (Though you may be able to construct a string using a delimiter that doesn't appear in any element.)

Comment: No delimiter was used to *declare* the array; that's the point. It's the conversion of the array to a single string that gets bound to `a` that can pose a problem. (I still think this answer is useful if one is stuck with an older version of `jq`, but the drawbacks still have to be acknowledged.)

Comment: yeah, I realized that after posting my comment. Thanks for the feedback here!!