# curl PUT with variables containing JSON data

Tags: json, bash, curl

I want to use curl to PUT data.  This works:

```
curl -X PUT --data '{ "xy": [0.6476, 0.2727] }' "http://"
```

I have a couple of bash variables that I'd like to use in place of the literals:

```
$key="xy"
$value="[0.6476, 0.2727]"
```

I've tried replacing the literals with quoted vars, but I get an error 'parameter not available'. I've tried combinations of nested and escaped quotes, but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48470049/3266847) about building a JSON object from Bash variables.

Comment: I tried using jq to build the JSON, but I couldn't get it to work with the array (value). -arg worked for the key, but not for the value. I tried -argjson and that rejected it.

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24300273/3266847) maybe.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153051/replace-a-key-with-array-in-bash; it uses a new feature in `jq` 1.6 for accessing positional arguments to `jq` as a list.

Comment: Thank you both. I suspect my problem came from further up the command chain (how the value got assigned to the array variable, which was not as clear cut as I showed) but I got diverted by the failure in `curl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this works for me :

```
 $ key='foo' 
 $ value='[ bar, bar ]' 
 $ echo "{ \"$key\": $value }"
 { "foo": [ bar, bar ] }
```

So this should work for you as well :

```
curl -X PUT --data "{ \"$key\": $value }" "http://google.com.uy"
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It does work now. I thought I'd tried that combination, but obviously not!

Comment: This is a bad idea. It assumes that neither `key` nor `value` contain any characters that need to be quoted in a valid JSON value.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with `Node`:

```
key="xy"
value="[0.6476, 0.2727]"
jsonData=$(node -e "console.log(JSON.stringify({$key: $value}))")
#jsonData output is: {"xy":[0.6476,0.2727]}

curl -X PUT --data $jsonData "http://"
```

But this only works for `Node.js` Developer or you have `Node` environment installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jq` (1.6 or later), use the `--jsonargs` option to take multiple JSON-encoded values as a JSON array accessible via `$ARGS.positional`:

```
$ key=xy
$ value=(0.6476 0.2727)
$ jq -n '{($k): $ARGS.positional}' --arg k "$key" --jsonargs "${value[@]}"
{
  "xy": [
    0.6476,
    0.2727
  ]
}
```

`--jsonargs` must come last, so that all remaining arguments are treated as values in the desired array. We use `--jsonargs` rather than `--args` so that you get an array of floating-point values, rather than an array of strings.

Once you have `jq` working, you pipe its output to `curl`, which uses `-` as the argument to `--data` to read the data from the pipe.

```
jq -n '{($k): $ARGS.positional}' --arg k "$key" --jsonargs "${value[@]}" |
   curl -X PUT --data - "http://"
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little please. It looks like just what I'm after, but I'm not really sure what '{($k): $ARGS.positional}' is doing.

Comment: The parentheses are required to force `$k` to be evaluated as an expression, rather than an ill-formed literal key. `$ARGS.positional` is an expression that evaluates to an array containing all the arguments that follow the `--args` option.

Comment: My `value` is set to a string containing the array I need to send (per my question), so my jsonargs part is `--jsonargs "[nnn, nnn]"` which is outputting `[[nnn nnn]]`. How can I get rid of that extra pair of square brackets please?